# All pages gives 404 except homepage and wp-login

Tags: login, 404-error

I have setup a local wordpress environment by downloading the files and database from live site. Then I changed the site URL in wp-options table and changed user password for login.

The homepage and wp-login page works fine but all the other posts gives 404 in frontend and after login in backend wordpress, it redirects to /my-account giving a 404 error page.

I checked the .ht-access file and it has this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN LiteSpeed
<IfModule Litespeed>
SetEnv noabort 1
</IfModule>
# END LiteSpeed
```

I think I need to save the permalinks in settings but the dashboard does not open for that. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to go directly to /wp-admin/options-permalink.php?

Comment: Yes. It says I don't care anymore